# Groovy: How can I read/compare lines from two files, without loading one or both files into memory

Tags: file, groovy

I need to merge two very large (larger than available memory) files using groovy.

To do this I've come up with the following pseudo code, that I can implement, except for the "read lineA from FileA".

```
// Pseudo Code:
open fileA for Input
open fileB for Input
open fileOut for Output

read lineA from fileA
read lineB from fileB

notDone = true

while (notDone) {
  if (lineA == lineB) {
    write lineA to fileOut;
    read lineA from fileA
    read lineB from fileB
  }
  elseif (lineA > lineB) {
    write lineB to fileOut;
    read lineB from file B
  }
  else { // lineA < lineB
    write lineA to fileOut;
    read lineA from fileA
  }
  if (lineA == null || lineB == null) {
    notDone= false
  }
}
```

The pseudo code above uses <,>and == to compare the lines, the real world example is more complicated.

Comment: Your pseudo code does not seems tp keep all input lines into memory. However you should try to use file.withReader { reader -> ....}

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, but can I use file.withReader, with two files at the same time? Where the next read source (fileA or fileB) depends on a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend helped me write this:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BufferedReader bufferedReader_A = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("view-connections_6.txt"));
BufferedReader bufferedReader_B = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("view-connections_7.txt"));
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter   = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("OUTPUT.txt"));
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
String lineA = bufferedReader_A.readLine()
String lineB = bufferedReader_B.readLine()
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Boolean notDone = true;
while(notDone) {
  if (lineA==lineB) {
    bufferedWriter.writeLine(lineA);
    lineA = bufferedReader_A.readLine()
    lineB = bufferedReader_B.readLine()
  }
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else if (lineA > lineB) {
    bufferedWriter.writeLine(lineB);
    lineB = bufferedReader_B.readLine()
  }
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else {
    bufferedWriter.writeLine(lineA);
    lineA = bufferedReader_A.readLine()
  }
  if (lineA == null || lineB == null) {
    notDone=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actualy, having read a bit about string comparison in groovy,  the == operator would seem the better fit here, than using lineA.equals(lineB), since it handels lineA==null. I'll freely admit, that the code should be more robust (test for edge cases), if it was meant for production ...